# Javascript : Anonymous function, access to global variables

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous

After hours of search, I Have a problem with my code Below. 
In fact, I'm not very far from answer I think but I'm still blocked…

I have an anonymous function called inside a loop and I want to access and refresh global variables but I tried with window.myvariable, with another function and nothing happen…

this my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < SHP_files.length; i++) {
            shapefile = new Shapefile({
                shp: "shp/polygon/"+SHP_files[i]+".shp",
                dbf: "shp/polygon/"+SHP_files[i]+".dbf",
                }, function(data) {

                    polygon_layer.addLayer(new L.GeoJSON(data.geojson,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature, style: polygonStyle}));
                    polygon_layer.addTo(map);
                    console.log(polygon_layer.getLayers()); // IS OK
                });
        };
        console.log(polygon_layer.getLayers()); // IS EMPTY !!
```

So, How i could transform this anonymous function in order to have something that I can access from my code who's following that ?

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my english not very good…

Comment: Do some research on asynchronous (non-blocking) coding patterns.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, what I'm seeing here is you passed a function as argument. Are you sure it's called in the constructor?

Comment: What does `new Shapefile()` do? If it loads the `.shp` and the `.dbf` files over AJAX, and the function is a success callback, the loading can happen asynchronously. ("in the background"). That means that after the loop ends, the files will only have begun to load, they'll be added to `polygon_layer` later.

Comment: @user2736012 That's pretty much a nonexplanation.

Comment: @millimoose: What is? I didn't attempt an explanation, but rather told the research topics to pursue. Is suggesting personal research verboten here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your typical problem with asynchronous code execution.  You example code does NOT execute from top to bottom.  In particular, your anonymous function does NOT get executed until `Shapefile` is done with whatever it is doing.  In the meantime, your JS gets executed in order. Therefore, the last line of your above code, will *probably* execute before the anonymous function ever will.

To fix this, you will need to trigger any code that depends on the `Shapefile` response from within its callback:

```
for (var i = 0; i < SHP_files.length; i++) {
    shapefile = new Shapefile({
        shp: "shp/polygon/"+SHP_files[i]+".shp",
        dbf: "shp/polygon/"+SHP_files[i]+".dbf",
        }, function(data) {
            polygon_layer.addLayer(new L.GeoJSON(data.geojson,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature, style: polygonStyle}));
            polygon_layer.addTo(map);
            executeMoreCode();
        });
};

function executeMoreCode() {
    console.log(polygon_layer.getLayers()); // IS OK
}
```

Comment: *"...will probably execute before the anonymous function..."* should read *"...will definitely execute..."*. Since the environment is single-threaded, any asynchronous code (like the callbacks) will need to wait for the thread to be available, which means the `console.log()` at the bottom will always execute first.

Comment: Well, I see your point, but I purposely said *probably* because it is true. Since the asynchronous call happens in a loop, I don't know how many execution cycles it takes up.  If we are talking about 100 or 200 iterations, there is a good chance that the first asynchronous call comes back before the loop gets exited.  So at that point, the `polygon_layer` array may no longer be empty.  But you are right in that it *definitely* will not have ALL the data yet.

Comment: Actually, no. Because the loop itself (followed by the call to `console.log()`) is synchronous, it will block any asynchronous activity until it's complete. So take an exaggerated situation where the `for` loop takes 1 second to complete. If the first callback is ready after only 100 milliseconds, it still won't be invoked because the `for` loop (and then the `console.log()`) will block it. Async code always needs to wait for any currently running sync code to finish.

Comment: Ok, thank you I understand the problem and why it was blocked. But I still have an interrogation because, I added a `console.log("i",i);` inside my success callback and after refresh, my console display `i=2` twice… like if the first passage was not complete… And my `polygon_layer` is also populated with the second shapefile twice…  In fact, I would loop from all the .shp and .dbf files of my folder, do some stuff and at the end of that do some final code… is it possible with 1 to n asynchronous ajax request ?

Comment: @ViotCamille: Your particular issue comes from non-blocking aspect of the code. Your callbacks will *always* happen after the loop and the last `console.log()` have finished. So ask yourself, what is the value of `i` after the loop is done? It'll be the last value that `i` was incremented to. But the issue in the code in the question isn't related to that. Your issue there is that you want the `console.log()` to run after all the callbacks are done. The answers given here don't really help with that.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand. Do I have to post another question in order to know how I can do stuffs after multiple asynchronous callback ?

Comment: @ViotCamille: You shouldn't have to. It's pretty clear looking at the code in your question that that is what you were after. Don't "accept" an answer that doesn't provide a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining your variables, in this case polygon_layer, outside of the for loop or the function. See the following example:

```
var f;
for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
    (function(){
        f = 10;
        console.log(f); // Outputs 10
    })();
}
console.log(f); // Also outputs 10
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is the cause of the problem. He/she probably already has `polygon_layer` defined outside the loop (and if not, it would just be a global variable anyway).  The issue is more than likely the asynchronous nature of the `Shapefile` call.

Comment: Likely true, was simply trying to address easiest solution first.